# How setMessage() works and sound changes in each row?

Tags: java, javasound

I am new to Java and sound API in java, I have written this code and I am not be able to understand how different sound is coming from different rows as I have not changed the instrument in the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.sound.midi.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class BeatBox {

JPanel mainPanel;
ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxList;
Sequencer sequencer;
Sequence sequence;
Track track;
JFrame theFrame;

String[] instrumentNames = {"Bass Drum", "Closed Hi-Hat", 
   "Open Hi-Hat","Acoustic Snare", "Crash Cymbal", "Hand Clap", 
   "High Tom", "Hi Bongo", "Maracas", "Whistle", "Low Conga", 
   "Cowbell", "Vibraslap", "Low-mid Tom", "High Agogo", 
   "Open Hi Conga"};
int[] instruments = {35,42,46,38,49,39,50,60,70,72,64,56,58,47,67,63};


public static void main (String[] args) {
    new BeatBox().buildGUI();
}

public void buildGUI() {
    theFrame = new JFrame("Cyber BeatBox");
    theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    JPanel background = new JPanel(layout);
    background.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

    checkboxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
    Box buttonBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(new MyStartListener());
    buttonBox.add(start);         

    JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    stop.addActionListener(new MyStopListener());
    buttonBox.add(stop);

    JButton upTempo = new JButton("Tempo Up");
    upTempo.addActionListener(new MyUpTempoListener());
    buttonBox.add(upTempo);

    JButton downTempo = new JButton("Tempo Down");
    downTempo.addActionListener(new MyDownTempoListener());
    buttonBox.add(downTempo);

    Box nameBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
       nameBox.add(new Label(instrumentNames[i]));
    }

    background.add(BorderLayout.EAST, buttonBox);
    background.add(BorderLayout.WEST, nameBox);

    theFrame.getContentPane().add(background);

    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(16,16);
    grid.setVgap(1);
    grid.setHgap(2);
    mainPanel = new JPanel(grid);
    background.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {                    
        JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox();
        c.setSelected(false);
        checkboxList.add(c);
        mainPanel.add(c);            
    } // end loop

    setUpMidi();

    theFrame.setBounds(50,50,300,300);
    theFrame.pack();
    theFrame.setVisible(true);
} // close method


public void setUpMidi() {
  try {
    sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    sequencer.open();
    sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
    track = sequence.createTrack();
    sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);

  } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
} // close method

public void buildTrackAndStart() {
  int[] trackList = null;

  sequence.deleteTrack(track);
  track = sequence.createTrack();

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      trackList = new int[16];

      int key = instruments[i];   

      for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++ ) {         
          JCheckBox jc = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(j + (16*i));
          if ( jc.isSelected()) {
             trackList[j] = key;
          } else {
             trackList[j] = 0;
          }                    
       } // close inner loop

       makeTracks(trackList);

   } // close outer


   try {
       sequencer.setSequence(sequence); 
     sequencer.setLoopCount(sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);                   
       sequencer.start();
       sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);
   } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
} // close buildTrackAndStart method


public class MyStartListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        buildTrackAndStart();
    }
} // close inner class

public class MyStopListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        sequencer.stop();
    }
} // close inner class

public class MyUpTempoListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
      float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor(); 
        sequencer.setTempoFactor((float)(tempoFactor * 1.03));
    }
 } // close inner class

 public class MyDownTempoListener implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
      float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor();
        sequencer.setTempoFactor((float)(tempoFactor * .97));
    }
} // close inner class

public void makeTracks(int[] list) {        

   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      int key = list[i];

      if (key != 0) {
         track.add(makeEvent(144,9,key, 100, i));
         track.add(makeEvent(128,9,key, 100, i+1));
      }
   }
}

public  MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {
    MidiEvent event = null;
    try {
        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
        event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);

    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
    return event;
}

} // close class
```

Above is the code , if anyone can tell me how `setMessage()` works, and about its arguments it will be a great help as I have seen all the documents and am not able to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drum instruments form a special case, as they do not have a specific pitch like on a piano or trumpet. A specific MIDI channel is used to transmit the playback of drum instruments. In General Midi, it is channel 10, but you will find synthesizers that can be programmed to receive drums on any channel.

In the case of a channel assigned to drum instruments (and also for special sound effects often included in synthesizers), the NOTE ON and NOTE OFF message information for the pitch is in fact used to select which drum or sound effect will play.

For instance, to play a bass drum instrument on channel 10, send the NOTE ON message as follows:

using channel 10 (coded 9) write 35 which is the note number used for the acoustic bass drum in the GM list above.

for more details refer to [1]: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/cmsip/readings/MIDI%20tutorial%20for%20programmers.html